# why is "cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option" for "no-" options only flagged by g++ when there is another warning?

Tags: c++, g++

```
> cat warning.cpp
#pragma foobar
> cat no_warning.cpp
#pragma message "foobar"
> g++ -Wall -Wno-foobar -c warning.cpp
warning.cpp:1:0: warning: ignoring #pragma foobar  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-foobar" [enabled by default]
> g++ -Wall -Wno-foobar -c no_warning.cpp
no_warning.cpp:1:17: note: #pragma message: foobar
```

Comment: Are you actually entering there command lines? Or are you using some kind of make utility? If make, most of them have a flag to print the commands before running. That will get us a sample command line that fails.

Comment: Of course I use make to begin with, but to isolate the problem, I am now using g++ on command line by hand.  I just switch the file name, and voila, the problem disappears.  For bigger files, the problem is there, for smaller, not.  What makes a difference, no clue so far.

Comment: Please add example of command that fails (full one), `gcc --version` and `g++ --version`

Comment: Here you go.  I've isolated it completely and I still don't have a clue.

Comment: `Note that in general we do not recommend the use of pragmas` - gcc manual. No ideas what this thing supposed to do. Full list of supported pragmas could be found at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html

Comment: The code is really strange: `#pragma message` is known to the compiler (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), `#pragma foobar` is not, and what do you expect now?

Comment: @MarkGaleck now I see the issue. But I would see it sooner, if you explicitly stated, what output you expect...

Comment: @vines I am sorry I should have clarified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

```
When an unrecognized warning option is requested (e.g., -Wunknown-warning),
GCC emits a diagnostic stating that the option is not recognized.

However, if the -Wno- form is used, the behavior is slightly different:
no diagnostic is produced for -Wno-unknown-warning unless other diagnostics
are being produced.

This allows the use of new -Wno- options with old compilers, but if something
goes wrong, the compiler warns that an unrecognized option is present.
```

In other words, suppose you have `foo.cc`, and GCC-4.9 warns about something (let's call it `foobar`) in it, but you believe that your use of `foobar` is safe.

Since you want to treat all warnings as errors (with `-Werror`), you dutifully add `-Wno-foobar` to your `Makefile`.

Now someone else tries to build your code with GCC-4.8. As stated above, this produces *no* warning and he succeeds.

If this did produce a warning, you'd be unable to both use the `foobar` construct and have a single `Makefile` that worked with both GCC-4.8 and GCC-4.9.